# Assign MPI Processes to Nodes

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have an MPI program that uses a master process and multiple worker processes. I want to have the master process running on a single compute node alone, while the worker processes run on another node. The worker processes should be assigned by socket (for example as it is done with the `--map-by-socket` option). Is there any option to assign the master process and the working processes to different nodes or to assign it manually, by consulting the rank maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment of ranks to hosts simultaneously with binding is possible via the use of rankfiles. In your case, assuming that each node has two 4-core CPUs, something like this should do it (for Open MPI 1.7 and newer):

```
rank 0=host1 slots=0-7
rank 1=host2 slots=0:0-3
rank 2=host2 slots=1:0-3
```

For older versions, instead of `slots=0:0-3` and `slots=1:0-3` one should use `slots=0-3` and `slots=4-7` respectively (assuming that cores are numbered linearly which might not be the case). Then the rankfile is supplied to `mpiexec` via the `--rankfile` option. It supersedes the hostfile.

Another option would be to do an MIMD launch. In that case one could split the MPI job into several parts and provide different distribution and binding arguments for each part:

```
mpiexec -H host1 -n 1 --bind-to none ./program : \
        -H host2 -n 2 --bind-to socket --map-by socket ./program
```

Comment: I'm submitting the jobs to a cluster. Do I have to parse the node_file or is there any easier way to find the name of the hosts?

Comment: What batch system does the cluster have?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I am aware of doing this is by using the [--hostfile](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpirun-hostfile) option of OpenMPI.

If you are using any decent batch system you should have a list of your hosts and slots in some simple file or environment variable and you can parse that into a hostfile.

If you run your application "by hand" you can generate such a list on your own.